# Internet Explorer 6+ https cacheing

Tags: php, internet-explorer, caching, https, internet-explorer-6

I am forcing some files to be cached (through headers like Cache-Control, etc). Are there any errors with Internet Explorer 6+ trying to cache those files if they're sent through https (SSL)?
Thanks for helping.

Comment: Are you looking for a yes/no answer or are you encountering an issue?

Comment: Are you experiencing some sort of errors with it?

Comment: I have not experienced any issues, I just want to be prepared beforehand, knowing that Internet Explorer has its share of errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there aren't. IE in general is not renowned for obeying standards, but *this* one it respects OK.

However, beware of proxies: some of them will not cache content until you have `public` in the `Cache-Control` header.

(and beware that IE6 will not use HTTP/1.1 with proxies by default, which means, by its twisted logic, that it won't either use keepalive or compression!)

Comment: HTTP Keepalive is the ability for a web client and server to exchange information so that only one connection is used to exchange several HTTP requests, instead of one connection per request. This is HTTP's `Connection` header. If keepalive is supported, the client will set this header to `keep-alive`. If not present or set to `closed`, keepalive won't be used. It is an essential part of a web site's performance.

Comment: What header can I set to make sure IE6 uses keepalive?

Answer (score 0):

One issue I'm aware of is that if you disable caching IE will not allow you to download files via HTTPS.  So if you application, say, allows user to download a generated file via HTTPS and you set no-cache header on it, IE will not allow the user to save such file on disk (because that would be *caching*)...

Comment: Beware: this is true _if and only if_ `no-cache` is present in the headers -- it will download the file anyway but will remove it before you have a chance to open it! Not putting `no-cache` but having `max-age=0` (which, all in all, disables caching) doesn't exhibit this problem -- and at least IE7 is also plagued with this problem, I don't know for IE8+